# Configuration file for .Net COM when invoked from old ASP

Tags: com, configuration, .net

there! I have a library written with .Net Framework 4. This library exposes some objects as COM via System.Runtime.InteropServices, which are registered with the regasm utility. These objects are intended to be used by an old (not .Net) ASP page, which is configured under an application that runs .Net Framework 2 (I know!!!) on IIS6 (Windows Server 2003).

Everything seems to work, except for the configuration file. When the .Net 4 COM object attempts to access System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager looking for a connection string, it gets a Null Reference exception. The web site has a Web.config file, and obviously the connection string is there, but the library can't find it. I think that it's because the Web.config is for the .Net applications running under IIS, and the COM library is seen as an external component.

I don't know where else the library might be looking for a configuration file. Changing the machine.config in the FW4 folder works, but I'd like to know if there is another location I could use, because machine.config is system wide and I don't want to pollute that, especially with connection strings. I tried adding a mylibrary.dll.config file in the DLL folder, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A DLL cannot have a .config file, only EXEs have them.  It is just not the right approach, use a .xml file in c:\programdata and deserialize it into a Config class object.

Comment: The problem is that I need to configure third party modules; things like log4net, web service http bindings, connection strings, all too deep in client code to manage with a custom configuration file. That is unless there's an easy way to merge my configuration file into the AppDomain Configuration object.